# Help me in understanding Heine-Borel theorem's proof

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, continuity, compactness, uniform-continuity

I am trying to understand the proof of Heine-Borel theorem [given here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Emorrow/334_15/uniform_continuity.pdf).

[image]

If I understand the meaning behind the phrases in box, I think it is enough for me to understand the proof.

Please explain the meaning behind the phrases in the box.

Comment: That's rather strange. Any textbook before discussing Heine Borel Theorem (or compactness) must describe exactly the terms which you have boxed. I find it hard to be believe that books could be so careless. Are you sure you have not studied these boxed terms before this theorem appears in your book?

Answer (score 3):

open covering of $K$ = a collection of open sets such that $K$ is contained in the union of this collection

covers $K$ = $K$ is contained in their union

finite sub cover = there exist sets in this collection, finite in number, such that they also cover $K$

$B_j$ cover $K$ = the union of $B_j$ contains $K$.

As mentioned in the comments: A set $K$ is compact (in the general, topological way) if and only if for every cover (see definition above) $(U_\alpha)_{\alpha\in A}$ of $K$ **that consists of open sets** we can find a finite subcover $(U_{\alpha_j})_{j=1}^N$.

Comment: Very insightful. I think you should also mention that the compactness of $K$ is equivalent to the existence of a finite subcover covering $K$

Comment: @omarS just did.